# Linear Algebra - Please direct me in the right direction

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: This is the problem that I have found some difficulty with. I am not even sure where to begin!]

This is the problem that I have found difficulty with. Can someone please direct me in the right direction. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What exactly do you not understand?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

**nonzero** is a keyword.

show that $$\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},  \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},  \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\right\}$$

is a basis for the column space of $A$.

Edit:

Alternative approach.

(a) First show that if $b \notin W$, then $Ax=b$ has no solution.

(b) Now consider $b \in W$,

Consider the system, 
$$\begin{bmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13} & A_{14} \\ 0 & A_{22} & A_{23} & A_{24} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & A_{34} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

First, let $x_3=0$, can you  solve for  $x_4$, then solve for $x_2$ and $x_1$?

Edit:

Possible solution for $(a)$:

If $b \notin W$, then $b$ can be writen as $\begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3 \\ b_4 \end{bmatrix}$ where $b_4 \neq 0$.

$$\begin{bmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13} & A_{14} \\ 0 & A_{22} & A_{23} & A_{24} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & A_{34} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} \sum_{j=1}^4 A_{1j}x_j \\ \sum_{j=2}^4A_{2j}x_j \\ A_{34}x_4 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3 \\ b_4\end{bmatrix}$$

We see that we have $b_4=0$ from the last row, which show that we can't find $x$ that satisfies the equality. The system is not consistent.

Possible solution to $(b)$.

Suppose that $b \in W$, We want to find a solution to the system.

$$\begin{bmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13} & A_{14} \\ 0 & A_{22} & A_{23} & A_{24} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & A_{34} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

By letting $x_3=0$, we have

$$\begin{bmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13} & A_{14} \\ 0 & A_{22} & A_{23} & A_{24} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & A_{34} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ 0 \\ x_4\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$ which is equivalent to

$$\begin{bmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12}  & A_{14} \\ 0 & A_{22}  & A_{24} \\ 0 & 0  & A_{34} \\ 0 & 0  & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2  \\ x_4\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

and it is equivalent to

$$\begin{bmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12}  & A_{14} \\ 0 & A_{22}  & A_{24} \\ 0 & 0  & A_{34} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2  \\ x_4\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3 \end{bmatrix}$$

Let the matrix on the left hand side be $C$.

Since $A_{11} \neq 0$, $A_{22} \neq 0$ and $A_{34} \neq 0$, $\det(C)= A_{11} \times A_{22} \times A_{34} \neq 0$, which shows that $C$ is invertible.

$$\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2  \\ x_4\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12}  & A_{14} \\ 0 & A_{22}  & A_{24} \\ 0 & 0  & A_{34} \end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3 \end{bmatrix}$$

Hence we manage to find a feasible $x$ which shows that the system is consistent.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: First identiy some independent columns from RREF, then you can perform column operations to obtain that.

Comment: I am sorry, I am very new to linear algebra. This is all very confusing.

Comment: Edited, is the alternative simpler?

Comment: It is much simpler and I will try my best to solve it! Thanks for all the help man!

Comment: Since you've wrote you are new to linear algebra, i'd say you should think of $Ax=b$ as a linear system of equations (for us obvious). Write down the four equations and think about if they are solvable or not.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: A system $Ax=b$ has a solution if and only if $Rank(A)=Rank[A:b]$. In your case, $Rank(A)=3$ (as $A$ is in its echelon form) and vector $b\in W$ (a $3-$ dimensional vector space) so that $Rank[A:b]=3$ for all $b_i\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: This wouldn't be an answer, would it?

Comment: @J.Khelly Well, it certainly is one excellent hint...and an almost-almost answer. What isn't clear here for you?

Answer (score 0):

Let the matrix be 
$A=\begin{bmatrix} a & m_1 & m_2 & m_3 \\ 0 & b & m_4 & m_5 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & c \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ where $a,b,c $  are non zero and $m_i$'s real numbers. Let $B=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{bmatrix}$ with $x_i$'s real numbers.

The whole point of $a,b,c$ being non-zero is ensuring you the existence of $a^{-1},b^{-1},c^{-1}.$ Make use if it.

Now consider the linear system $AX=B.$ Row reducing the matrices wouldn't affect the solution.(Why?)

Hence by applying row-reduction, you get
$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & m_2-m_4m_1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & m_4 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}X=\begin{bmatrix}x_1/a-m_1x_2/b-m_3x_3/c+x_3m_4m_5/c\\x_2/b-m_5x_3/c\\x_3/c\\x_4\end{bmatrix}$

which basically means $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & m_2-m_4m_1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & m_4 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}X=\begin{bmatrix}\text{some real number}\\\text{some real number}\\\text{some real number}\\ x_4 \end{bmatrix}$

Also think why $x_4$ has to be zero for a solution to exist.